# VBA Macro that filters by month, pastes data for that month only on different sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sheet (named "UserInput") with data from 1959-2013 (starting at 10/1/1959)

i.e.:

---

```
                                 "UserInput" Sheet


                Column A           Column C          Column I
                  DATE           UNGAGED FLOW    PERM. WITHDRAWAL & PASS
        Row 24: 10/1/1959             9.3               7.7
                10/2/1959             5.2               6.4
                10/3/1959             6.3               4.3
                10/4/1959             3.8               7.5
                ... 
                ... 
     Row 19839: 12/31/2013            5.5               9.1
```

I need to write a macro that filters by `month` starting from A24, then pastes the date, 'ungaged flow' (starting at C24) and 'permitted withdrawal and passby' (starting at I24) values for each day to its corresponding sheet (I have separate sheets named "OCTOBER", "NOVEMBER", "DECEMBER", etc. with "ungaged flow" and "permitted withdrawal and passby" columns)

i.e.:

---

```
                               "OCTOBER" Sheet

              Column A          Column B            Column C
                DATE          UNGAGED FLOW      PERM. WITHDRAWAL & PASS

       Row 3: 10/1/1959           9.3                 7.7
              10/2/1959           5.2                 6.4
              10/3/1959           6.3                 4.3
              ...
              ...
              10/1/1960            n                   n
              10/2/1960            n                   n
              ...
              ...
              10/1/1961            n                   n
              10/2/1961            n                   n
              (etc.)
```

And so on for each month (October thru September).

This is what I have so far (I'm fairly new at VBA so don't cringe):

```
Sub getmonths()


Sheets("UserInput").Activate

Dim monthpassby(12) as Double       ' ungaged flow
Dim monthwithdrawal(12) as Double   ' permitted withdrawal and passby
Dim months As Variant

   ' need code to read-in data?

 'check for month in the date
  Sheets("October").Range("A3").Select

  Do Until IsEmpty (Sheets("UserInput").Range("C24").Value)

  months = Month(Sheets("UserInput").Range("A24").Value)

  Sheets("October").Range("A3").Value = monthpassby (months)
  ActiveCell.Offset(0,1) = monthwithdrawal (months)     

  ActiveCell.Offset (1,0).Select

Loop

End Sub
```

I've spent about a week researching this problem. I really need help just filling the in-betweens. I've also tried using `Advanced_Filter` and recording my macro. A pivot table was considered, however I need the "Ungaged Flow" and "Permitted Withdrawal and Passby" data on each sheet for the individual months to calculate two more columns ("Exceedence Value" and "Streamflow") which will also be on the individual month sheets. Then I have to produce a flow duration curve for each month on the corresponding month sheets. I haven't used pivot tables to that extent, but if you know a way I can do that with a pivot table that would be awesome. And also, this will eventually be a User Input tool so the "Ungaged Flow" and "Permitted Withdrawl and Passby" values will be dependent on what values the user has.

Comment: Actually it's very good when you explicitly refer to each sheet that you need to work with! the problem is that you don't increment the rows. I'll show you an example shortly

Comment: Are the *ungaged flow* and *permitted withdrawal and passby* column labels in the monthly worksheets in the first row?

Comment: The first empty space for the value(s) to go starts at A3 ("date" column), B3 ("ungaged flow") and C3 ("permitted withdrawal and passby")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example based on your initial code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetMonths()
    Dim monthpassby(12) As Double
    Dim monthwithdrawal(12) As Double
    Dim currentMonth As Variant
    Dim wsUserInput As Worksheet
    Dim wsOctober As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, totalRows As Long

    Set wsUserInput = Worksheets("UserInput")
    Set wsOctober = Worksheets("October")

    totalRows = wsUserInput.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    For i = 24 To totalRows 'iterate through each row on sheet UserInput

        currentMonth = Month(wsUserInput.Range("A" & i).Value2)

        'copy array values to sheet October, column A and B, starting at row 3
        With wsOctober.Range("A" & (i - 21))
            .Value2 = monthpassby(currentMonth)             'Column A
            .Offset(0, 1).Value2 = monthwithdrawal(months)  'Column B
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

.

It will probably not accomplish the task, but it can be fixed if you confirm what I understand:

On sheet UserInput you have data similar to this:

```
        Column A    Column C    Column I
Row 24: 10/1/1959   ungaged1    permitted1
Row 25: 10/2/1959   ungaged2    permitted2
Row 26: 10/3/1959   ungaged3    permitted3
... 
... 
Row N: 12/31/2013   ungagedN    permittedN
```

The code should copy:

- "ungaged2" and "permitted2" to Sheet "February", row 25
- "ungaged3" and "permitted3" to Sheet "March", row 26

If so, then are the columns "ungaged flow" and "permitted withdrawal and passby" named spelled exactly the same on all of the "months" sheets?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to clarify that my date column is formatted mm/dd/yyyy.
 So ungaged 1-3 and permitted 1-3 are all going to the "October" sheet. I've refined my question a bit more if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

With no sample data, some of this is a bit of a guess.

```
Sub xfer_monthly_data()
    Dim iMON As Long, lc As Long, nrw As Long, ws As Worksheet
    Dim c1 As Long, c2 As Long
    With Sheets("UserInput")
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        .Columns(1).Insert
        With .Range(.Cells(23, 1), .Cells(24, 2).End(xlDown))
            With .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1)
                .FormulaR1C1 = "=MONTH(RC2)"
            End With
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count, 10)
                For iMON = 1 To 12
                    .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=iMON
                    If CBool(Application.Subtotal(102, .Columns(2))) Then
                        Set ws = Worksheets(UCase(Format(DateSerial(2015, iMON, 1), "mmmm")))
                        c1 = Application.Match("ungaged flow", ws.Rows(1), 0)
                        c2 = Application.Match("permitted withdrawal and passby", ws.Rows(1), 0)
                        nrw = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
                        .Offset(1, 1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Copy _
                          Destination:=ws.Cells(nrw, 1)
                        .Offset(1, 3).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Copy _
                          Destination:=ws.Cells(nrw, c1)
                        .Offset(1, 9).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Copy _
                          Destination:=ws.Cells(nrw, c2)
                    End If
                    .AutoFilter field:=1
                Next iMON
            End With
        End With
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        .Columns(1).Delete
    End With
End Sub
```

Inserting a new column to be used as a 'helper' with a formula that determines the numerical month of the dates from the original column A allows a filter to be easily applied. Bulk copying operations of the visible cells are always faster than looping through individual cells and determining their validity. The helper column is removed after the operation has been completed.

This could be speeded up further by turning off screen updating, calculation and events (at a minimum).